# How can I take a screenshot of an alert using Selenium webdriver in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

Hi I'm a new user of selenium. I'm trying to take a screenshot of an alert using selenium webdriver in ruby.

```
@driver.find_element(:name, "updateButton").click
@driver.save_screenshot "./#{Time.now.strftime("Alert_Screenshot___%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S")}.png"
```

Instead of taking a screenshot, this error is thown:

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError

Of course I can accept the alert:

```
@driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

and then take a screenshot. But I want to know is there way to take the screenshot *while* the alert is being prompted?

Comment: What is the point of taking a screenshot of the alert given that Selenium can get the message for you. An alert is created by the browser, not by the page.

Comment: Indeed. The only reason of getting screenshot is to check alert's message... but you can do that with `Selenium`, no need to take a screenshot..

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to take screenshot for complete screen, not only the browser. So you can use [xwd](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xwd.1.html) to take a screenshot of the root window:

```
xwd -display :0 -root|xwdtopnm |pnmtopng > $1
```

Comment: I'm working on windows and this is part of a big script. Any idea how to do it using selenium webdriver?

Comment: Alert is not a WebElement, so it is difficult to handle with Selenium but you can try Winium for same (it is developed using Selenium as base) https://github.com/2gis/Winium